# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'port'

Tags: python, sockets, attributeerror

I am trying to build a chat application using python.

When I try to run the program I get

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'port'

Here is my server code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print("Server will start on host: ",host)
port = 8080
s.bind ((host.port))
print("")
print('server done binding to host and port successfully' )
print("")
s.listen(1)
conn,addr = conn.accept()
print(addr, "Has connected to the server and is online--")
print("")
```

And this is my client code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

s = socket.socket()
host = input(str('Please enter the Hostname of the server: '))
port = 8080
s.connect((host.port))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling the `bind()` function is incorrect. Instead of:

```
s.bind ((host.port))
```

It should instead be:

```
s.bind((host,port))
```

Looks like a little syntax error.